# Read and Display data using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tyring read from the data listCards and displaying the list of cards in a loop using jquery.

But i'm getting only an empty array in console.

Please tell me what i'm doing wrong ?

```js
<script>
var listCards = [{
    "cardTitle": "Sample Ttile",
    "cardDate": "05 April 2017",
    "cardLinkURL": "#",
    "cardLinkDTM": "data-tracker-id=\"cards_1_1\" data-tracker-type=\"button\" data-tracker_ei=\"cards_1_1\" "
},
{
    "cardTitle": "Sample Ttile 2",
    "cardDate": "05 April 2017",
    "cardLinkURL": "#",
    "cardLinkDTM": "data-tracker-id=\"cards_1_1\" data-tracker-type=\"button\" data-tracker_ei=\"cards_1_1\" "
}]
</script>
```

So what i've done so far is

```js
$(".list-view").on('click', staticListCards);

     function staticListCards(){
      console.log("Called");
      $.each(listCards, function (index, value) {
       console.log(value);
       });  
     }
```

Comment: You set `listCards = staticListCards`, then you call `listCards.forEach(...`. Therefore, you're calling `forEach()` on a `function`, hence the error. I'm not quite sure what you're expecting to happen.

Comment: remove this `var listCards = staticListCards;console.log(listCards);` and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

It is a generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays.

```js
var listCards = [{
    "cardTitle": "Sample Ttile",
    "cardDate": "05 April 2017",
    "cardLinkURL": "#",
    "cardLinkDTM": "data-tracker-id=\"cards_1_1\" data-tracker-type=\"button\" data-tracker_ei=\"cards_1_1\" "
  },
  {
    "cardTitle": "Sample Ttile 2",
    "cardDate": "05 April 2017",
    "cardLinkURL": "#",
    "cardLinkDTM": "data-tracker-id=\"cards_1_1\" data-tracker-type=\"button\" data-tracker_ei=\"cards_1_1\" "
  }
];
var len = listCards.length;
var txt = "";
$.each(listCards, function(key, value) {
console.log(value);
  txt += "<tr><td>" + value.cardTitle + "</td><td>" + value.cardDate + "</td></tr>";
});
if (txt != "") {
  $("#table").append(txt);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Date</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Arun Kumar: Try this

Comment: i'm not able to read the values of listCards, as it is loading inside a script tag in the page level and in the JS file i'm writing the code for staticListcard()

Comment: Its working thanks :-) its my bad i was resetting listCards to an empty array and removing that code it's working fine.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the Jquery each loop like :

```
$.each(listCards, function(index, value) {
    }
```

In this code **"value"** means the single element of **"listCards"** so you can use it directy you dont need to use index 
I hope it will help you

Comment: I've done the changes, but i'm getting only an empty array in console

Comment: Your "listCards" may be empty please check the size of it